# OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credentials with Dynamic Client registration

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, native, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I am implementing login within a new native application (iOS and Android) and deciding on the kind of authentication to adopt. There are some quite clear guidelines around OAuth that state that this should be done using an external agent (browser) and this leads me to Authorization Code Grant with PKCE

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252

Implementation here: https://appauth.io/

However, my designers and product owners are sceptical. They dont see that kind of login very much (they dont like the address bar) and want to explore the Resource Owner Password Credentials option. Essentially direct login. Their argument is that it is simple and familiar.

I dont want to compromise security and as such I am resisting this option. But... I have read some articles that seem to suggest that this could be secure if I dynamically generate the client used for the auth request:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.1

> The authorization server MUST NOT issue client passwords or other
> client credentials to native application or user-agent-based
> application clients for the purpose of client authentication.  **The
>
> authorization server MAY issue a client password or other credentials
> for a specific installation of a native application client on a
>
> specific device.**

This is backed up by AppAuth documentation here:

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android#dynamic-client-registration

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7591

Am I interpreting this correctly? I am considering initial user registration in-app that returns an access token that can be used to dynamically generate a client (with secret) that can be used for login using ROPC.

I am thinking to be secure then this dynamically generated client should only be used for login for the single user - one client per user, but maybe one client per device is also secure enough.

It seems a little 'hand rolled', so I am nervous. Am I right to be so?

Comment: With ROPC you need to secure the app because it has to handle the credentials, while in other flows the app remains ignorant. You're shifting responsibility to a public app. Please read: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications While ROPC is in the category 'obsolete', AppAuth is in the category 'Best Current Practice'. Take that back to the other designers/product owner. Unless they've real arguments you shouldn't investigate ROPC. Being sceptical means that they are not convinced yet.

Comment: Thanks @Ruard. I have read that article and it's one of the many that makes me want to avoid ROPC. It looks like we will make the decision to use the appauth implementation (Auth code). Bugs me that I can't figure out how so many other players are implementing this. So many, including really big names seem to be using ROPC. Which seems bizarre given its obvious flaws.

Comment: Perhaps the real big players simply don't trust apps as a rule. In which case changing authentication will not increase security. I can imagine that they don't rely on authentication tokens only. Security has multiple dimensions. They probably use additional information and algoritms to protect their resources. Like when Google sends you an e-mail when you login from another device.

Comment: If you follow best practices ROPC should work well enough. Also, I would go with a client per device rather than a client per user.

Comment: Google uses PKCE implementation for sign-in using device's browser rather than embedded user-agent. This is true if you use google single sign-in from another app. (2017 on wards). One issue with ROPC is that, user don't know where the sign-in is authenticated, this will attract an attacker to create a similar look and feel app on apple store.

Comment: Its true that Google etc use PKCE for sign in from other apps. But from their own apps then they (and others) use something else. What can it be if its not ROPC? Seems like they are going agaist current guidelines.